# CSS help trying to integrate adsense into post

Tags: css

I'm using the following div classes to integrate adsense into the post page.

```
.adsense {
    clear: left;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}

.spacing {
    float: left;
    height: 170px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

The problem however is that all the posts have a image (250x250) and when using the above class, the adsense class is pushing the image as well. The image class is as follows.

```
.content img.alignleft {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

The wordpress loop the_content is called within the 'content' class, which is as follows:

```
.content p, ul, ol {
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is there a way to move the adsense code further below the post (300px down) so that the post's image stays the place where it is while the adsense block is called further below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you have a problem with your html, not your css. the only way of breaking out of flow with the html is using position:absolute and putting a top:300px value in, adding padding to the bottom of the picture to hold the div you are moving.
what you actually want to do is go into the template and just move the bit of the code that is generating the image to being generated before the adsense, therefore it will be below the image in the flow.

you will have to post either an example page or some more code to get a better answer i think.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Using the position:absolute now makes the adsense code to float over the content wrapped within the <p> tags

Comment: it will do, yes. postion:absolute will break it out of the flow and put it on a layer on top. by using the top: left: right: and bottom: you can adjust this to be positioned relative to the nearest parent with position:relative. you will then have to add either a padding or margin space to float it over. like I said, this is basically a really hacky way of doing it and should be avoided for just fixing up the template.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should contact the template author.